# Alphabetical sorting of elements class attributes

Tags: jquery, class, sorting, attributes, alphabetical

i need to **sort alphabetically the class attributes of the "A"** element. The purpose is to create lightview groups.

i use **this script to take the class of each "DIV" element and put it to the "A"** element. Note that the several "DIV" have different class.

I can concatenate the class with or without space. So i can put a space between each class for a srcipt that come after this one to sort them, or maybe someone have a solution for that script to do it directly?

**Script**

```
$(function(){
    $('div.level_1').find('.lightview').attr('data-lightview-group', function () {
        return $(this).closest('.level_1')[0].className.split(" ").slice(0).join("");
    });
});
```

**Result code after this script**

```
<div class="euItem generation_y _2013 level_1">
    <img border="0" src="/sport/sport_2014/gallery/images/images_thumbnails/bike-tbn.jpg" class="euImg" alt="Bike">
    <h4>
        <a href="/sport/sport_2014/gallery/images/bike.jpg" class="link-ico lightview" data-lightview-group-options="controls: 'thumbnails'" data-lightview-group="euItemgeneration_y_2013level_1"><span>Bike</span></a>
    </h4>

    <p>Praesent placerat purus in lobortis egestas. Etiam lectus augue, viverra in ultricies vitae, accumsan eu arcu. Phasellus auctor fringilla sem non imperdiet.</p>

    <span class="clear">&nbsp;</span>
</div>

<div class="level_1 euItem eu_sport_forum _2013">
    <img border="0" src="/sport/sport_2014/gallery/images/images_thumbnails/relay-tbn.jpg" class="euImg" alt="Relay">
    <h4>
    <a href="/sport/sport_2014/gallery/images/relay.jpg" class="link-ico lightview" data-lightview-group-options="controls: 'thumbnails'" data-lightview-group="level_1euItemeu_sport_forum_2013"><span>Relay</span></a>
    </h4>

    <p>Praesent placerat purus in lobortis egestas. Etiam lectus augue, viverra in ultricies vitae, accumsan eu arcu. Phasellus auctor fringilla sem non imperdiet.</p>
    <span class="clear">&nbsp;</span>
</div>

<div class="level_1 _2013 generation_y euItem">
    <img border="0" src="/sport/sport_2014/gallery/images/images_thumbnails/bike-tbn.jpg" class="euImg" alt="Bike">
    <h4>
        <a href="/sport/sport_2014/gallery/images/bike.jpg" class="link-ico lightview" data-lightview-group-options="controls: 'thumbnails'" data-lightview-group="level_1_2013generation_yeuItem"><span>Bike</span></a>
    </h4>

    <p>Praesent placerat purus in lobortis egestas. Etiam lectus augue, viverra in ultricies vitae, accumsan eu arcu. Phasellus auctor fringilla sem non imperdiet.</p>

    <span class="clear">&nbsp;</span>
</div>

<div class="level_1 euItem eu_sport_forum _2013">
    <img border="0" src="/sport/sport_2014/gallery/images/images_thumbnails/relay-tbn.jpg" class="euImg" alt="Relay">
    <h4>
    <a href="/sport/sport_2014/gallery/images/relay.jpg" class="link-ico lightview" data-lightview-group-options="controls: 'thumbnails'" data-lightview-group="level_1euItemeu_sport_forum_2013"><span>Relay</span></a>
    </h4>

    <p>Praesent placerat purus in lobortis egestas. Etiam lectus augue, viverra in ultricies vitae, accumsan eu arcu. Phasellus auctor fringilla sem non imperdiet.</p>
    <span class="clear">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```